# Can buildr include the result of a subproject's package in the current project's resources?

Tags: build, buildr

If I want to package a subproject's jar inside the main jar, I can do this sort of thing:

```
define 'library' do
  project.version = '0.1'

  define 'subproject' do
    package :jar
  end

  package(:jar).include(project('subproject').package(:jar),
                        as: 'org/acme/library/subproject.jar')
end
```

This will lazily build the jar in the subproject, right before it is needed for packaging into the main jar, and everything works.

Problem is, my tests want to use the jar file as well, so the logical place for it is in the resources. So I wonder how I'm supposed to copy something build by another project into the resources for this project. The docs are notably lacking any examples of this and mostly focus on how to copy one directory of files to another.

This is what I tried:

```
 resources.from(project('subproject').package(:jar),
                as: 'org/acme/library/subproject.jar')
```

It fails:

```
RuntimeError : Source directory $HOME/Documents/library/subproject/target/library-subproject-0.1.jar doesn't exist
$HOME/Documents/library/buildfile:38:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

To my surprise, this seems to be the one place in buildr which *eagerly* evaluates the existence of a build product instead of setting it up as a lazy dependency...

I can work around this as follows:

```
# Crappy workaround to eagerly create target dir in subproject.
mkdir_p project("lucene#{ver}").path_to(:target)

resources.from(project("lucene#{ver}").path_to(:target)).
                 include(project("lucene#{ver}").package(:jar))
```

I don't like this because it still eagerly evaluates the directory, which forces me to create that directory long before any of the build is being run. Meaning that even when I run `buildr clean`, it's creating this directory. Yuck.

So what's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The way we typically do this is to not create any packages with the top level project and instead use a subproject to define the two packages. i.e

```
define 'myproject'
  ...
  define 'model' do
    ...
    package(:jar)
  end

  define 'server' do
    ...
    package(:war) do |war|
      war.libs.clear
      war.libs << project('model').package(:jar)
    end
  end
end
```

This allows much easier management of dependencies and ordering of builds. Hope that helps!

Comment: Packaging into a package already works fine here actually, the problem is that I want to package into the resources build destination. The question shows that I got that to work as well, but using a hack which seems unnatural. That said, using a subproject for the end package looks like it will tidy up the build file, so I think I'll do that anyway. :)